# WSO2 -Migration of ESB 4.8.1 to 5.0.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am learning wso2 and  have 4.8.1 version of wso2 installed in my machine.I am planning to migrate to esb 5.0.0.Please help me in the steps involved in migration and also how to validate the conversion to the new version.

Answer (score 0):

The following WSO2 link has the steps of migration and validation. Please refer.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release